# Replace variable letters in formula strings using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel formulas that look like below

**Example 1**

```
=SUMIF('TRx Wkly NT'!$A:$A,"AdderAKl* XR*",'TRx Wkly NT'!BS:BS)/10^3
```

**Example 2**

```
=SUMIF('TRx Wkly NT'!$A:$A,"amphe* ER* prasco*",'TRx Wkly NT'!BS:BS)/10^3+SUMIF('TRx Wkly NT'!$A:$A,"amphe* ER* teva*",'TRx Wkly NT'!BS:BS)/10^3
```

**Example 3**

```
=SUM('Baseline Trx Wkly NT'!BS:BS)/1000-SUM(PX29,PX73,PX108)/1000
```

In these formulas, "BS:BS" refers to an entire column. I need a sub that replaces "BS:BS" with "ColumnLetterVariable:ColumnLetterVariable" with VBA

How do I achieve this? I don't even know where to begin. Do I use Regex?

**Problem 1**:  I don't know what I am replacing. "BS:BS" is not constant; it changes all the time. It can be `AA:AA` one day, or even single letters such as `Z:Z` the next day.  VBA needs a way to recognize the `Column:Column` part of the string

**Problem 2**: "BS:BS" may show up in multiple positions within the formula, such as in Example 2. All of these need to be replaced with my VBA variable.

**EDIT**: The `$A:$A` part of the example formulas do NOT need to be replaced. Just the `BS:BS` part, which changes all the time.

Comment: `myCell.Formula = Replace(myCell.Formula, "!BS:BS", "!A:A")`

Comment: @TimWilliams  Why would that work?  "BS:BS" is not constant. It is just an example. This part of the string changes all the time. (explained in my Problem 1)

Comment: It's not clear in your question that you don't know what it is you're replacing.  What about the `$A:$A` in the first example?  How would you know which references need switching out?

Comment: @TimWilliams Apologies for the confusion, I modified the original post. You are correct, I don't know what I am replacing. Things tagged with $ do NOT need to be switched out.

Comment: It might be better to just generate a new formula. Ex: `=SUMIF('TRx Wkly NT'!$A:$A,"AdderAKl* XR*",'TRx Wkly NT'!" & myCol & ":" & myCol & ")/10^3` where `myCol` is the column you need

Answer (score 1):

Try this code - I think you could use regular expressions to solve your problem (all comments and pattern explanation are in code):

```
Sub RegexTest()
    Dim regex As Object, result As String, pattern As String, replacement As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    ' Define inputs: pattern and replacement value
    pattern = "!([A-Z]+):(\1)"
    ' Pattern explanation: match exclamation mark (!) literally, then match one or more capital letters: [A-Z]+,
    ' those captured letters will  be in capturing group defined with brackets (),
    ' then match semicolon (:), then match exact same text that was captured in first group
    replacement = "Column:Column"
    ' Test function
    result = RegExReplace("TRx Wkly NT'!$A:$A,""AdderAKl* XR*"",'TRx Wkly NT'!BS:BS)/10^3", pattern, replacement)
    MsgBox result
    result = RegExReplace("TRx Wkly NT'!$A:$A,""amphe* ER* prasco*"",'TRx Wkly NT'!BS:BS)/10^3+SUMIF('TRx Wkly NT'!$A:$A,""amphe* ER* teva*"",'TRx Wkly NT'!BS:BS)/10^3", pattern, replacement)
    MsgBox result
    result = RegExReplace("Baseline Trx Wkly NT'!BS:BS)/1000-SUM(PX29,PX73,PX108)/1000", pattern, replacement)
    MsgBox result
End Sub
Function RegExReplace(inputString As String, pattern As String, replacement As String) As String
    ' We need to create RegExp object to use regular expressions
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.pattern = pattern
    RegExReplace = inputString
    ' Since Replace method replaces one value at a time, you need to replace it until no more matches are found
    Do
        RegExReplace = regex.Replace(RegExReplace, "Column:Column)")
    Loop While regex.Test(RegExReplace)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.

Comment: May not get to actually try this until a week later. Will circle back.